# How to show loading function before get data from server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, loading

I use Ajax and SweetAlert2 library to use alert UI. I search the how can I show the loading process during get data from server and I thought I can use beforeSend function. I write code like this.

So I put the Loading Process code inside the beforeSend but I don't know why It's not working. So I want to check is it works in beforeSend code so I write console.log code inside it and it actually works. But I don't know why the Swal.showLoading(); code is not working.

When I just type it in google console it works.

Loading Code is Simple.

```
Swal.showLoading();
```

And I want When it finish it show Finish Code.

```
/* Mypage */
function getData() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Do you want to get data from Github?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Get DATA!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // contentType: "application/json",
                url: `/${userId}/admin/getData`,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    Swal.showLoading();
                    console.log('Loading');
                },
                success: function (redrawData) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(redrawData));
                    let existTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
                    existTable.destroy();
                    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                        aaData: redrawData, // Returned Data from Server
                        aoColumns: [{
                                mData: 'id',
                                "render": function (value, type, row) {
                                    return `<a href="/${userId}/${row.id}">${row.id}</a>`;
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'name'
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'type'
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'url'
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'imgurl',
                                "render": function (value, type, row) {
                                    return `<img src="${row.imgurl}">`;
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'sumlang'
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'pjdate1'
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'pjdate2'
                            },
                            {
                                mData: 'githuburl'
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                },
                complete: function () {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Get!',
                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                        'success'
                    )
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Failed to save',
                        'If this message is output continuously, please contact to administrator.',
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Why not call `Swal.showLoading();` right before making the `$.ajax` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the `showLoaderOnConfirm` to true to show the preloader when you click the continue button. Then, add the ajax call inside the `preConfirm`. Just make sure to return the response and catch any errors.

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Submit your Github username',
  input: 'text',
  inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: 'off'
  },
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Look up',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (login) => {
    return fetch(`//api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText)
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(
          `Request failed: ${error}`
        )
      })
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: `${result.value.login}'s avatar`,
      imageUrl: result.value.avatar_url
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I never used SweetAlert but I have taken a look on their [website exmaple](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) and found this

```
const ipAPI = 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'

Swal.queue([{
  title: 'Your public IP',
  confirmButtonText: 'Show my public IP',
  text:
    'Your public IP will be received ' +
    'via AJAX request',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: () => {
    return fetch(ipAPI)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => Swal.insertQueueStep(data.ip))
      .catch(() => {
        Swal.insertQueueStep({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Unable to get your public IP'
        })
      })
  }
}])
```

They use `fetch` with `preConfirm` in their exmaple, but in your case, I guess you can try to use `preConfirm` attribute that return the `Promise` created by the JQuery [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function

**Example:**

```
/* Mypage */
function getData() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Do you want to get data from Github?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Get DATA!',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
        preConfirm: function(){
            return $.ajax(...); //Your ajax function here
        }
    });
}
```