# Loading indicator showLoading is not showing up

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, sweetalert2

I am learning and trying to implement Sweetalert2 and at the same time, I am trying to mix it with Fetch API.

I have a [html](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/resources/templates/documents.html) element like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" th:onClick="uploadMultipleUsingSwal()">Upload</a>
```

and blend of Sweetalert2 and my [JavaScript](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/resources/static/js/fileupload.js) (Fetch API - POST) goes like this:

```
function uploadMultipleUsingSwal() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Upload File(s)',
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            fetch('/uploadMultipleFiles', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then((response) => {
                Swal.showLoading();  // This is NOT working
                response.json();
                Swal.fire(
                    'Uploaded!',
                    'All files uploaded successfully.',
                    'success'
                ).then(() => {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Upload Failed!',
                    error,
                    'error'
                )
            });
        } else if (result.isDenied) {
            Swal.fire('No file uploaded', 'Try again !', 'info')
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to show loading (Spinner) while waiting for the file upload to finish but somehow it doesn't show up and no errors in the console whatsoever.

What I am missing here? Or what I am doing wrong?

Update:

Following the link shared by Felix, I tried this:

```
function uploadMultipleUsingSwal() {
    let htmlstring = '<input type="file" id="file-selector" multiple>';

    Swal.fire({
        html: htmlstring,
        title: 'Do you want to get data from Github?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        showDenyButton: true,
        denyButtonText: 'Cancel',
        showCloseButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Upload',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
        preConfirm: async function() {
            const fileselector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
            const fileselectorValid = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#file-selector').value
            if (!fileselectorValid == "") {
                Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please select at least one or more file(s). !`)
            }
            var files = fileselector.files;
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
                formData.append("files", files[index]);
            }
            return fetch('/uploadMultipleFiles', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then((response) => {
                response.json();
                Swal.fire(
                    'Uploaded!',
                    'All files uploaded successfully.',
                    //'All files uploaded successfully. Response Code: ' + response.status,
                    'success'
                ).then(() => {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Upload Failed!',
                    error,
                    'error'
                )
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But it broke the validation I had where I check for 0 files.

Comment: Is your loader  a GIF in a folder?

Comment: Its inbuilt function in Swal2

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641690/how-to-show-loading-function-before-get-data-from-server

Comment: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/778

Comment: I tried but it shows up for few seconds but breaks the validation. Please see update.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what does broke mean? Bypassing that particular statement?

Comment: I meant to say, if the files size is 0 I dont get validation message now.